# How to change the project default Time format in Rails

Tags: datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

Before I updated Rails, the default Time format the API was returning was `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`. Now it returns `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:sss'Z'`. I want to change it back due to apps that rely on the old time format. How can I change this PROJECT default format that `Time::DateTime`'s `to_s` method returns?

Edit:

I should probably mention I started using the `active_model_serializer` gem. Not sure if that makes a difference. My guess is this change happened after the update from Rails 4.0.x to 4.1.x. Also I want to change this format for the project. This format changed between Rails versions. `active_model_serializer` uses `to_s`, so it makes more sense to override how to project sets this. I don't know where that is.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`strftime`](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime):

```
Time.now.strftime("%Y-%M-%d %H:%m:%S%Z")
```

one of your gems is probably overriding the `DateTime` `to_s` method. you can just override it again with you own method back

Comment: The question title states the `project Time format`. I never formatted it. It defaulted to returning `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`.

Comment: Looking at the source shows no overriding of to_s or even referencing any specific objects. Although you are not wrong you aren't answering the question. Maybe it would be helpful to tell me how to change the default to_s implementation of Time in a Rails project so it reflects all my code. If it ins't possible, well that's a different story.

Comment: you just need to create a class named `DateTime` with one method `to_s` and thats it, it will override the default DateTime to_s implementation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this:

```
# config/initializers/time_with_zone.rb

module ActiveSupport
  class TimeWithZone
    def as_json(options = nil)
      iso8601
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can augment the Ruby built-in `Date::DATE_FORMATS` and `Time::DATE_FORMATS`

```rb
DATE_FORMAT = "%m/%d/%Y".freeze
TIME_FORMAT = "#{DATE_FORMAT} %l:%M%P".freeze

format_defaults = {
  default: DATE_FORMAT,
  date_time12: TIME_FORMAT,
  date_time24: "#{DATE_FORMAT} %H:%M",
}.freeze

Date::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(format_defaults)
Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(format_defaults)
```